# Overlapping nav bar and content

Tags: html, css

[image: Screenshot of my web page]
I am experimenting with css and HTML but i am getting an error.I am retrieving data from firebase and displaying it in form of table.But table is not getting displayed properly.Table header and data is not arranged properly and they are getting above nav bar.

```js
var database = firebase.database();
database.ref('Inventory').on('value', function(snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    var config = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyA8rtBYqR3hkj3YyzumZd98YNVrf1MbYz4",
      authDomain: "ngoapp-74c5f.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://ngoapp-74c5f.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "ngoapp-74c5f",
      storageBucket: "ngoapp-74c5f.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "273078401200"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    var content = '';
    snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
      var val = data.val();
      content += '<tr>';
      content += '<td>' + val.category + '</td>';
      content += '<td>' + val.name + '</td>';
      content += '<td>' + val.quantity + '</td>';
      content += '</tr>';
    });
    $('#ex-table').append(content);
  }
});
```

```css
#bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
}

#bg img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#ex-table {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  padding-right: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 140px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: .5;
  top: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
  border-spacing: 20px;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 200px;
  padding-right: 200px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.0/firebase.js"></script>

<div id="bg">
  <img src="https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/teenager-friends-dancing-and-laughing-on-a-rooftop-party-picture-id513546832" alt="">
</div>

<table style="width:100%" id="ex-table">
  <tr id="tr">
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
</table>
<script>
</script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="addinventory.html">Add Inventory</a></li>
    <li><a href="viewinventory.html">View Inventory</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Please suggest a solution for this problem.If i can have a code to display table in a better way then that will be advantageous.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you getting data from firebase correctly?

Comment: Yes data is received correctly.